# What is Spark doing to vector values when writing to CSV?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Here is the result of some code that writes predictions from a `LogisticRegression` model to json:

```
    (predictions
        .drop(feature_col)
        .rdd
        .map(lambda x: Row(weight=x.weight,
                           target=x[target],
                           label=x.label,
                           prediction=x.prediction,
                           probability=DenseVector(x.probability)))
        .coalesce(1)
        .toDF()
        .write
        .json(
        "{}/{}/summary/predictions".format(path, self._model.bestModel.uid)))
```

Here is one example resulting JSON object:

```
{"label":1.0,"prediction":0.0,"probability":{"type":1,"values":[0.5835784358591029,0.4164215641408972]},"target":"Male","weight":99}
```

I would like to be able to output the same data to a CSV file (preferably with just `probability.values[0]` (the first element of the array of values). However when I use the same snippet of code as above, but replace `.json` with `.csv`, I get the following result:

```
1.0,0.0,"[6,1,0,0,280000001c,c00000002,af154d3100000014,a1d5659f3fe2acac,3fdaa6a6]",Male,99
```

What is going on with the 3rd column (an array with a bunch of values quoted in a string)?

Answer (score 0):

"probability" is more than a vector, it's in json format, so what you see is a weird object serialisation.

Try to dump it as a string first

```
withColumn("probability", col("probability").cast("string"))
```